# How can I position img and iframe on left, p on right column (without using containing divs)?

Tags: html, css, css-float, multiple-columns

let's say I have some markup like this:

```
<div id="content">
<h2>Post 1</h2>
<img src="dummy.jpg">
<iframe src="youtube.com/foobar"></iframe>
<p>Sample text.</p>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>

<h2>Post 2</h2>
<img src="dummy2.jpg">
<iframe src="youtube.com/foobar2"></iframe>
<p>Sample text2.</p>
<p>Second paragraph2.</p>
</div>
```

How could I style this, so that all the images and iframes are in a sort of "left column" with iframe under the image,  whereas the paragraphs are on a right sided column?

float:left; for img and iframe obviously doesn't work, because the iframe floats left to the img.

Thanks for any input, by now I read too much about inline elements, paddings and floating to make it all work together.

As I want to implement this into a getsimple Site (with users who can't to much html markup) it should work without div-containers.. (also if I needed them I would actually doubt this content/design seperation that CSS always promises, but makes it so hard to implement ;))

If I work with floating, I am aware that I should clear this with the h2 headings as to get a new block for each post.

```
#content h2 {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Using `clear` on the iframe and img seems to solve your "iframe floats left to the img" problem. (I'd explain why, but I never truly understood how clearing works, it's more of a "let's see what this does.." and tada! sort of thing for me)

Comment: Ah, that did it, thank you! However: I would like to have the p continue in it's column, because after img and iframe it just wraps under it.. and I dont want to add an articial padding on the bottom, or only one that adjusts to the length of the paragraph somehow.. get what I mean? (sorry for sloppy clarifications)